# ( Logarithmic Equation ) Solve for x.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

$(x+1)^{log(x+1)} = 100(x+1)$

Attempt at solution :
$$ (x+1)^{log(x+1)} = 100(x+1)$$
$$= x^{log(x+1)} + 1 = 100x +1$$
$$=(x+1)+1=100x+1$$
$$=−98=99x$$ 
$$x=−98/99$$
But the answer given in the Practice sheet is :

## $$= x=−9/10 or 99

Comment: $100(5+1)=500+1$ ????? See your second step ($100(x+1)=100x+1$).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming $x>-1$,
$$ (x+1)^{\log(x+1)}=100(x+1) $$
implies:
$$ \log^2(x+1) = \log(100)+\log(x+1) $$
hence by setting $\log(x+1)=y$ we have:
$$ y^2-y-2\log(10) = 0 $$
or:
$$ y = \frac{1\pm\sqrt{1+8\log 10}}{2}$$
from which:
$$ x=\exp\left(\frac{1\pm\sqrt{1+8\log 10}}{2}\right)-1. $$
If $\log$ is intended to be in base-$10$, the same process leads to $x=99$ or $x=-\frac{9}{10}$.

Comment: Thanks for answering !  But can you explain what did you do  in the first 2 steps (before the quad equation)

Comment: @shaitaan Taking logarithm both sides, and using the identities:
$$\log a^b = b\log a$$
$$\log ab = \log a + \log b$$
And simplifying.

Comment: @Jack How does that lead to $x=-\frac{9}{10}$ or $x=99$. I'm stuck here , can you  provide some detail  on the calculation part please ?

Comment: @Jack D' Aurizio can you show calculation in last part, how  $ x=99 $

Answer (score -1):

Here is my solution.I have left solving of quadratic equation to you

[image]

Comment: thanks for the help ! i dont get what you did at the 2nd and 3rd step in the LHS only

Comment: @shaitaan in second step i have taken log on both sides and in third step i have used $log(a^{b})$ = $bloga$

Comment: oh i knew that but i didn't see it , sorry and thanks , also can you explain how this : $$y = \frac{1\pm\sqrt{1+8\log 10}}{2}$$  Leads to this : $$x=\exp\left(\frac{1\pm\sqrt{1+8\log 10}}{2}\right)-1$$ ? What is that 'exp' ? Sorry for asking too much , i'm just a high-school fresher, plus there's nobody here to ask around. Thanks

Comment: We have $log(x+1)=y$. So $x+1=e^{y}$. Also exp(ANYTHING) means e raised to power ANYTHING

Comment: oh no , i haven't learned natural log yet.

Comment: i cant seem to reach the answer yet, $$ e^1 and e^-2 $$ is what i have calculated , i don't know where i'm going wrong, will anybody show show the calculation part after the last step please ?

Comment: @shaitaan it will be better if you post your work so that your mistake can be pointed out

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26552/discussion-between-shaitaan-and-taylor-ted).